# 500,000,000 records , int field timestamp indexed , will mysql handle searching through this query?

Tags: mysql

assuming i have a MySQL table with 500 million records within it

it have a column `ts` , which is indexed and have timestamps as values .
is it efficient doing a

`select * from table where ts>=time()-24hours`

as well as for last 24 hours/week/month/year ?

or shall i go for nosql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that MySQL will often throw away indexes when dealing with large date ranges.  Your ">=", which technically a range (ending in "now"), might be an exception for the optimizer since it should be able to jump to the starting point...

If you can stand the time to build the table, use `EXPLAIN` to see if it's using the index.

Hopefully you don't need to `SELECT *`.  If you only need a couple of smaller columns in your results, put them in the index, too, which will keep MySQL from having to read the underlying wider rows from disk.

Comment: Actually i need select * to generate a report . what do yo umean with throw away ? it will act as if there were no index ?

Comment: All databases make the decision as to whether using an index is faster than just doing a table scan.  When the date range gets "too" big, I've seen MySQL throw away the index and fall back on the table scan, which would be impossibly slow.  Hope that's more clear.  The comment about "select *" was an optimization to allow the database to only look at the index info and not have to read the underlying row from disk.

Comment: Nice information , will it be better to write timestamps to the nearest hour ? , and probably moving very old data (older than 3 months) to another table and unify their timestamps to the closest month ? thus using 2 tables , one for recent reports (newer than 3 months - detailed day by day) and one for older months (less details month by month) ?

Comment: All other things being equal, the fewer records you have in your database and the shorter your columns, the faster your query will be.  I've built reporting tables that used "buckets" of information for 5-minute periods, and then would rollup those into hourly "buckets" at the end of a week.